# Azure VM Scale Sets Historical Data & Performance

Tags: azure, azure-vm-scale-set

I have an Azure Subscription that is used by our automation to spin up VMSS. Based on logging, it appears that every VMSS request takes about 25 mins to complete. It seems like an exorbitant amount of time to complete.

1. Where can I find historical trends on how long each of my VMSS request took on my Azure subscription?
2. When I spin a single VM using the same image & SKU it only takes a few minutes. Why does it take 10 times the time when I request it through VMSS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. If you are talking about Azure Control plane operations - you can check activity log, its available under the resource group and under the vmss resource.
2. thats how the platform is built. vmss is a bit more complex than a single vm, so takes more time to create it.